Byobu/zsh: Access command history of specific pane
I use Byobu, which is tmux-based, and inside I have a zsh shell with Oh My Zsh.
I want to have a way to access the command history of a given Byobu pane, i.e. something like the output of history 1, except I want to specify a pane ID and get the history output for that pane. I want this for a keyboard-bound action which could run while the specified pane is busy with some long-running command. How can I do that?
